# Simple Java method returns 0 no matter the user input

Tags: java, methods, return-value

This method is supposed to return the integer that the user enters as long as it is only an integer (not a String, float, etc.) and as long as that integer is one of the options in the given list of options. I want to use this method throughout my program whenever I give the user a list of options they need to choose from. These lists will have varying sizes thus I pass as an argument the maximum value (maxValue) that the user could possibly choose thus giving the method the size of the list.

```
//This method handles the players input and checks if the number entered is one of the options listed or not

public static int response(int maxValue){ //the parameter is the number of options in the particular list

    response = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean check = true;

    while(check){
        try{
            int yesOrNo = response.nextInt();
            if(yesOrNo > maxValue || yesOrNo <= 0){ //checks if the int entered does not exceed the list size or go below zero
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, that number was not one of the options. Please reselect your choice.");


            }else{
                check = false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){ //catches an exception when the user enters a string or anything but an int
            System.out.println("Please only use digits to make a selection.");
            response(maxValue);
        }
    }

    return yesOrNo; //returns the user's response. Well, it is supposed to.

}
```

I am a beginner with regards to programming. I am learning Java through online tutorials and trial and error on dumb, little programs I make. I am working on a fun little text-adventure and am still in the beginning stages.

The trouble I'm having is because this method will only return 0. Isn't `yesOrNo` being assigned the integer that the user inputs through the scanner `response`? Why is it only returning 0?

---

Thank you for your responses. I understand now that I needed to declare my `int yesOrNo` outside of the `try` because it was out of scope, as you all put it, being declared within.

BUT a few mentioned 'there is a completely unnecessary function call in the catch block'. The only problem is if I remove it there is an infinite loop created with the `System.out.println("Please only use digits to make your selection.")` when the user inputs Strings or other non-int values.

Here is my updated code:

```
//This method handles the players input and checks if the number entered is one of the options listed or not
public static int response(int maxValue){ //the parameter is the number of options in the particular list
    response = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean check = true;
    int yesOrNo = 0;

    while(check){
        try{
            yesOrNo = response.nextInt();
            if(yesOrNo > maxValue || yesOrNo <= 0){ //checks if the int entered does not exceed the list size or go below zero
                System.out.println("I'm sorry, that number was not one of the options. Please reselect your choice.");


            }else{
                check = false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){ //catches an exception when the user enters a string or anything but an int
            System.out.println("Please only use digits to make a selection.");
            response(maxValue);
        }
    }

    return yesOrNo; //returns the user's response. Well, it is supposed to.

}
```

---

After reading other post before just asking another question I found many others facing the same issue. It was correct what some were saying that the infinite loop was created because when the Scanner encounters an error it doesn't remove the token of that error thus causing the while loop to read the same error over again infinitely. Here is what i read exactly:

"As per the javadoc for Scanner:

'When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.'

That means that if the next token is not an int, it throws the InputMismatchException, but the token stays there. So on the next iteration of the loop, getAnswer.nextInt() reads the same token again and throws the exception again. What you need is to use it up. Add a getAnswer.next() inside your catch to consume the token, which is invalid and needs to be discarded."

So now that infinite loop problem is fixed :) Onto finding what else I need to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Your entire try/catch is inside a while loop, why are you making a call to response again inside the loop? This is not necessary, as the loop should automatically repeat.   Also, declare your int yesOrNo outside the loop and then read the value in the try block. This is better on memory, as the int won't be redeclared every time the loop runs.  You should also be sure to close your scanner just before your return statement.

Comment: Unassigned integers in java are automatically assigned zero. Useful fact.

Comment: No one is mentioning the fact that there is a completely unnecessary function call in the catch block?

Comment: @EvanBechtol But without that declaration there is an infinite loop created when the method catches an exception.

Comment: @BrandonVance No, the way your program is laid out it should go back through the try/catch again because your "check" value is still set to true. You more than likely have a bug somewhere involving your response.nextInt(); it will catch the null-terminator left-over from the previous entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yesOrNo` goes out of scope because you declared it within the try block. Move the declaration outside to where it is in scope when you return it.

```
Boolean check = true;
int yesOrNo;
```

Comment: This should also be put before the while in order to evade the same scope issue as with try.

Answer (score 0):

`yesOrNo` you're returning is not same as

```
int yesOrNo = response.nextInt();
```

in your loop. The yesOrNo from the loop disappears (goes out of scope) at the closing `}` of `try`.

There has to be another `int yesOrNo` somewhere. Look for it.

Answer (score 0):

The only this can compile is if `yesOrNo` is declared as a class or instance variable, unseen in this code snippet.

The declaration of `yesOrNo` that we do see is declared inside a `try` block, shadowing the `yesOrNo` being returned.  But there's no reason for it to be a class or instance variable.

Remove it from the class declaration, and declare it locally, before the `try` block, so it's in scope when it's returned.

```
int yesOrNo = 0;
try{
    yesOrNo = response.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see "int yesOrNo" inside while loop. The value read inside while loop scope is limited to that. Declare that variable outside and try.